# Selecfield set options from array

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Hi I have a json with array of values and I want to set this values as options to the selectfield. Not sure how to go ahead with this scenario.Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code for json and javascript function which returns the xtype selectfeild

```
          var json= {
                "metric": {
                    "areaInput": ["um", "mm", "cm", "m", "dm", "km"],
                    "areaResult": ["um", "mm", "cm", "m", "ha", "dm", "km"],
                    "volumeInput": ["mm", "cm", "m", "km"],
                    "volumeResult": ["ml", "tsp", "tbs", "l", "mm", "cm", "m", "km"],
                    "weight": ["g", "kg", "mg", "t"]
},
      "imperial": {
            "areaInput": ["in", "ft", "yd", "fur", "mi", "nmi"],
            "areaResult": ["in", "ft", "yd", "mi", "nmi", "acre"],
            "volumeInput": ["in", "ft", "yd", "mi"],
            "volumeResult": ["in", "oz", "fl.oz", "pt", "qt", "gal", "tbs", "tsp", "cups", "ft", "yd", "mi"],
            "weight": ["oz", "lb", "t", "oz.tr.", "grains"]
        }
                },


            selectBoxUnit: function(eachInput){
                   var options = [];


        for (h in json.metric) {
          options.push({text: json.metric[h], value: h});
        }
            Ext.getCmp('myselect').add(options);
                    return {
                        xtype: 'selectfield', 
                        usePicker : false,
                        itemId: eachInput.itemId+"selectfield",
                        name: eachInput.itemId,
                        id:'myselect',
                        flex: 1,
                        options: options, 
                        listeners: {
                            change: function (field, value) {
                                    field.setOptions([{
                                        value: "newvalue",
                                        text: "My new value"
                                    }], true);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to Sencha Touch 2. I write this example for you. May be it will help you. You must set datastore to 
selectfield. After this you can very easy add items to this
datastore and options will be created.

```
Ext.define('OptionModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'text', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
        ]
    }
});

var optionsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'OptionModel'
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Test',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Select',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            label: 'Choose item',
                            id: 'selectItemId',
                            store: optionsStore
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Add new item',
                    listeners: {
                        tap: function () {
                            var optionValueText = "Item " + optionsStore.getCount();

                            // here is the magic 
                            optionsStore.add({
                                text: optionValueText,
                                value: 'somevalue'
                            });

                            // here we set new added item
                            // to be selected (active into select)
                            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#selectItemId')[0].setValue(optionValueText);
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```